# AES 256-Bit key generation to comply with specific Checksum C#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am given this validation code, to prove if an AES Key is compliant:

Class Cypher.cs

```
public bool ValidateCheckSumAESKey(string strAESKey)
    {

        string base64AESKey = strAESKey;
        const int N = 3;
        const string valSumCalc = "qx6p";


        SHA256Managed h = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] base64AESKeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64AESKey);
        byte[] sha256hash = h.ComputeHash(base64AESKeyBytes);

        byte[] sha256hashNbytes = new byte[N];
        Array.Copy(sha256hash, 0, sha256hashNbytes, 0, sha256hashNbytes.Length);

        string base64sha256hashNbytes = Convert.ToBase64String(sha256hashNbytes);

        string result = base64sha256hashNbytes.Replace("=", "");


        if (0 == string.Compare(result, valSumCalc))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So, an example key given "cWhay3H4asTvRzXzXGZQ3KyBEu9BZaIxl8J+L4Bhr5A=" passes the checksum.

I am trying to generate an AES Key using

```
   public string Encrypt()
    {
        AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        return Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
    }
```

But even if I do in the Main Class

```
 Cypher cf = new Cypher();

 bool boolValid = false;
 while (!boolValid)
 {
    string strKey = cf.Encrypt();
    boolValid = cf.ValidateCheckSumAESKey(strKey);
 }
```

...it can run for hours without finding a single valid key. How could I shorten the loop to find a complying key faster?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Admittedly, vastly truncating the SHA 256 output should reduce the search space but, at the end of the day, you're still trying to perform a preimage attack against SHA256. It *should* be computationally expensive.

Comment: What's the security advantage of doing this in the first place?

Comment: I don't know what is the advantage. It's just a mandatory rule for establishing "valid" AES keys as per request.

Comment: Seems like an arbitrary imposition made by someone who doesn't knows what security is to begin with, or it being a deliberate backdoor to break the encryption with a known key. **ANY** 256 bits number *is a perfectly valid AES key*, the more random is it, the better.

Comment: Well knowing the customer good I do know it's a way to knack the code. But I can't do anything about it. Still 6 hours running the validation, not a single key found. I'm starting to consider the idea of running the code for weeks and making a pool with whichever valid results I find...

Comment: Your question basically boils down to finding a successful preimage attack on SHA256, none of which are known as of now. In fact, **the algorithm is specifically designed to make what you want as difficult as possible**. It may well take years (probably millions) to find even one "valid" key. I would like to know how you came with the example one.

Answer (score 0):

The 4 base64 characters represents 24 bit of information, giving you 16777216 different combinations.

Measuring the speed of `Encrypt()` should give you a good indication on how long it will take to try out 16-17 million cases on average.

Consider that you generate a new random key on each call .. random data can often be a limited resource on the system that might slow your down. Specifically try measuring the speed of `new AesManaged();`.

Comment: 100,000 combinations generated = Elapsed=00:15:39.4728012. So to try them all it would take long... and I may need up to 30-40 keys. Ideas?

Comment: Is it the generation of keys, or the other parts that uses the time ? If it's the generation of keys, you might make the keys by 'hand', instead of through the use of `new AesManaged()`

Comment: I measured  Encrypt + Validate. In the While loop i just added a Stopwatch to give me the time after 100,000 tries (none of which successful btw). What do you mean by making keys "by hand"?

Comment: In your code you only use AesManaged to get a key, nothing else. If this is the part that takes the time, you can investigate alternatives to generate the key. But first .. identify what uses the time.